# Java use standard library without import

Tags: java

Is there a way to use the standard library class Scanner without an import statement?

My professor is the type to include overly difficult problems that you are not expected to actually complete but aside from decompiling the standard library and adding all of the .java files to the project I am at a bit of a loss.

Edit: to clarify, this is the exact wording of the lab description:
"Use a scanner to get an integer value from the user.  Your program may not use any import statements."

Comment: "Your program may not use any import statements" - I'd love to understand the rationale behind this. I can understand they could be directing you not to use third-party libraries, but you can do next to nothing without referencing the standard classes directly or via import

Comment: @BrianAgnew To **teach** people what `import` does. Or rather, to **test** people if they understood what they have been taught, i.e. that `import` is just convenience, and is never *needed*.

Comment: @Andreas I have defiantly learned that now but it was never covered explicitly up to this point.

Comment: @DeSync But I bet it was covered, even if not explicitly that way. The assignment is a test to see if you *understand* what has been taught, not just a test to see if you can blindly repeat something back from a book without understanding it. Good tests are like that, and you actually learn from them, since they force you to think and draw conclusions you might not have made yourself (yet).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. You can fully qualify them on usage:

```java
java.util.Scanner scanner = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
```

---

The import statement is not about the compiler asking *where can I find the class?*, but rather *which class do you mean?*

With the import statement you say to the compiler: *"Everytime I say `Scanner`, I actually mean `java.util.Scanner`. So please save me some typing.*

So indeed, as Andreas already mentioned in the comments. `import` is not necessary, it's just convenience.

Also note that all classes from the `java.lang` package (for example `System` in the abovementioned example) are implicitly imported ([JLS § 7.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.3)), so you can always use them without an import statement.