# How to call a method from the Arrays class without using an import statement?

Tags: java

I tried to call this method from the Arrays class without using an import statement:
Could u please tell me what´s wrong?

```
//import java.util.Scanner;

class ArraySorting {
    /**
     * @param array unordered sequence of strings
     * @return ordered array of strings
     */
    public static String[] sortArray(String[] array) {
        // write your code here
        java.util.Arrays.sort  input = new  java.util.Arrays.sort(System.in);
        String string = input.next();
        String[] str = string.split(" ");
        java.util.Arrays.sort (array);
        System.out.println(string.toString(array));
    }
      return (array);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        sortArray();
    }
}
```

Thanks alot

Comment: You're trying to declare a *variable* of type `java.util.Arrays.sort`. It isn't a type, it's a method. It's not at all clear to me what you expect the first line of your `sortArray` method to do.

Comment: You are calling `sortArray()` without its parameter `String[] args`. It is really unclear how you are passing array to your method.
On the other hand, why would you avoid import?

Comment: And trying to return outside a method (you have too many `}`). Neither of those last two issues are related to imports. I suggest you edit your question to show a version which *does* work but uses an import, and then (as a second piece of code) your attempt to change it just to not use the import. At the moment, the code is broken in too many ways to be a good SO question.

Comment: It's also unclear why you *want* to avoid using an import statement in the first place.

Comment: I must according to the task, without using an import.

Comment: Well, you can write `Arrays.sort(...)` or `java.util.Arrays.sort(...)` and you won't need an import.  But you do have to call it **correctly**, by passing an array as the argument.  What were you hoping to accomplish with `java.util.Arrays.sort(System.in)`?

Comment: I need to call this method from the Arrays class without using an import statement.

...and make it so your sortArray method returns the array after it was sorted

Comment: Related: [Java use standard library without import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61498784/java-use-standard-library-without-import/61498826#61498826).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method to *sort* the array should be cleaned out of the redundant code and has to be as simple as:

```java
public static String[] sortArray(String[] array) {
    java.util.Arrays.sort (array);
    System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(array));
    return array;
}
```

Next, the test must be rewritten to read a line, split into arrays of strings to be sorted with `sortArray`:

```
public static void main(String ... args) {
    java.util.Scanner input = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
    String string = input.nextLine(); // read entire line not a single token
    String[] str = string.split(" ");
    System.out.println("before sort: " + java.util.Arrays.toString(str));
    String[] sorted = sortArray(str);
    System.out.println("str: " + java.util.Arrays.toString(str));
    System.out.println("sorted: " + java.util.Arrays.toString(str));
}
```

[Online demo](https://ideone.com/pCdZOm)

```
before sort: [abc, aad, 0123, 456, zxy, aabc]
[0123, 456, aabc, aad, abc, zxy]
str: [0123, 456, aabc, aad, abc, zxy]
sorted: [0123, 456, aabc, aad, abc, zxy]
```

Note: `Arrays.sort` modifies its input array so actually method `sortArray` may be `void`.

Comment: ` class ArraySorting {
    public static String[] sortArray(String[] array) {
        java.util.Arrays.sort (array);
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
            System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(array[i]));
        }
        return array[i];
    }
}
`How can I get the output without square bracket?
I changed only the part **for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){ System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(array[i])); } return array[i]; }** But it doesn't work.

Comment: ** FEEDBACK 
Failed test #1 of 3. Wrong answer**

This is a sample test from the problem statement!

**Test input:
y d b u t f m h x q
Correct output:
b d f h m q t u x y**

Your code output:
before sort: [y, d, b, u, t, f, m, h, x, q]
[b, d, f, h, m, q, t, u, x, y]
str: [b, d, f, h, m, q, t, u, x, y]
sorted: [b, d, f, h, m, q, t, u, x, y]

Comment: You're free to remove the test prints to comply with your tests

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot for your Answer. my question is: How can I get the output **without square bracket**?

Comment: don't use `Arrays.toString` to convert an array to a string -- this method formats the output and adds the brackets and commas between the elements. You could print each element in a loop: `for (int i = 0, n = array.length; i < n; i++) { System.out.println(array[i] + " ");}  return array;`

Comment: `public static String[] sortArray(String[] array) {
        java.util.Arrays.sort(array);
        return array;`
Now, i have the final Answer. Thanks a lot.